# How do i minify amplify application?

Tags: javascript, aws-amplify

I'm using react/amplify stack. After publishing app, i realized that all code there is not minified, i'm able to open any component and see it's unminified source code. As i understood, amplify builds app based on it's amplify.yml file. I didn't change there anything and it looks like this:

```
version: 0.1
backend:
  phases:
    build:
      commands:
        - '# Execute Amplify CLI with the helper script'
        - amplifyPush --simple
frontend:
  phases:
    preBuild:
      commands:
        - npm ci
    build:
      commands:
        - npm run build
  artifacts:
    baseDirectory: build
    files:
      - '**/*'
  cache:
    paths:
      - node_modules/**/*
```

I can see a command there - 'npm run build' which i suppose should build app and then publish it as minified version. So why it hasn't happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm run build` is going to do whatever is configured in the scripts section of your `package.json`. Likely you'd want to configure environmental variables to indicate what type of build to do. Here is how the `create-react-app` project has chosen to do it:

```
...
"scripts": {
    "build": "REACT_APP_ENV=development react-scripts build",
    "build:development": "REACT_APP_ENV=development react-scripts build",
    "build:production": "REACT_APP_ENV=production react-scripts build",
...
  },
...
```

Using this pattern, you can either manually specify what type of build you want, or set the environment variable and just run `npm run build`.

[Environmental variables in Amplify](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/environment-variables.html) are configured under App Settings > Environmental Variables.